# Adding North Arrow in ArcGIS Online web application/map?

Tags: arcgis-online, north-arrow

I would like to add a north arrow for online applications/maps in the ArcGIS Online platform.

I can't seem to find if this is possible and/or how?

Comment: Welcome.  Please take the community tour:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour   Do you want this to show up on a print out of the map or on screen?

Comment: Both if possible.

Comment: I don't see a way to add one or the need to add one. The map doesn't rotate/tilt. North is always on-top.

Comment: While North may always be up, often a cartographer includes a north arrow for aesthetic or stylistic reasons (even in a purely digital application).

Comment: I assume your using one of the default templates in ArcGIS Online, and currently none of them (except the 3D ones) allow you to rotate the map view.  I also assume your underlying web-map is using a coordinate system where north is always in the same direction (i.e. up).  I tend to agree with @Petunia that it is not neccessary for the online version, but you can easily add it to your print layouts.  If you really need one in the online view, you could either add a graphic into one of the sidebars of the many templates if this suffices?

Comment: Yes, the purpose to include a North Arrow is purely aesthetic in this case. It is a common element that would be viewed by my audience as "missing or not included". So I would certainly like to have it represented on the map. I know North is always up however many in my audience may lack the Cartographic acumen to be aware of that.

Comment: I'll try adding it as a graphic and see if that works.

Comment: What are the 3D ones you mention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This blog post

[ESRI Blog Post (Part 2)](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/12/08/adding-labels-to-arcgis-online-web-maps-part-2/)

... shows a method that involves converting text to features and adding the features in as you would a regular feature layer in your ArcGIS Online map. Skip ahead to figure 8 in the link I provided (the "RISK" map), and read through the paragraph after that figure. You have to have the font on your system and you will be doing much of the work using "ArcMap" to convert the graphics to features and then you'll be able to bring the result into ArcGIS Online.

Comment: This seems as another possibility that I'll try.